# Authorship of Mevo Hatalmud

Tags: authorship, geonim

Who authored the Mevo Hatalmud? It is commonly assumed to have been authored by R. Shmuel Hanagid, and this is assumed by [R. Ishtori Haparchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishtori_Haparchi) in his *Kaftor Vafreach* (ch. 5) and by the Chida in *Shem Hag'dolim*, but [this page](http://www.britannica.com/topic/Mevo-ha-Talmud) merely says that he is "generally believed to be the author". I have heard that it was actually authored by Sh'muel Bar Chofni.

So, who wrote it?

---

A source earlier than R. Ishtori Haparchi stating that it was authored by R. Shmuel Hanagid would suffice for an answer. (Although I would prefer a more thorough discussion of the matter rather than a mere assumption.)

Answer (score 12):

R. Ishtori seems to be the earliest source who explicitly ascribed the *mevo* to R. Shmuel HaNagid. A later but important source, [R. Yosef Sambari](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/13061-sambari-cattawi-joseph-ben-isaac) (Divre Yosef [pp. 403](https://www.ybz.org.il/_Uploads/dbsArticles/ShtoberOCR.pdf)), ascribed the *mevo* to the Nagid of Egypt, ca. 1140, R. Shmuel b. Hananya. However, the notion that the *mevo* was authored by [R. Shmuel b. Hofni](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_ben_Hofni) surfaced in the light of  the *genizah* documents.

---

Now for a “(thorough) discussion on the matter”...

From various sources in medieval literature we are informed of a treatise (specifically, a *mevo*) on the Talmud authored by R. Shmuel b. Hofni. In fact, some sources (e.g. [R. Yona ibn Janah](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonah_ibn_Janah) in his Sefer Ha’sharashim, [p. 114](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36864&st=&pgnum=154)) quote selections from it. In 1880 [Avraham Harkavy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Harkavy) published a monograph on RS b. Hofni (subtitle, ‘Zichron HaGaon Rav Shmuel ben Hofni U’sfarav’ [p. 4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32034&st=&pgnum=6&hilite=)) and proposed that the aforementioned work served as a precursor for RS HaNagid’s *mevo* (Harkavy referenced [ShIR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Judah_Loeb_Rapoport) who surmised the same) but no certain conclusions could’ve been drawn as long as the original treatise was lost and internal evidence unable to be ascertained. Then came the discovery of the [Cairo Genizah](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairo_Geniza) trove.

One of the documents identified in the *genizah* was this treatise written in Arabic. After examining its content, [Arthur Cowley](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Cowley_(librarian)) published an extract of it (Zichron LeAvraham Eliyahu [pp. 161](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36672&st=&pgnum=211)) and, based on the similarity of the material between the two *mevo’ot*, determined that it was none other than the source for the later compiled ‘*mevo* of R. Shmuel HaNagid’, the latter being an abridged Hebrew translation of the former. Later on, [Mordechai Margaliot](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/margaliot-margulies-mordecai) published ‘Sefer Hilchot HaNagid’ and agreed  (Intro., 68ff.) that RS b. Hofni’s work was the archetype but disagreed with the idea that it was RS HaNagid who had compile the later *mevo* and instead advanced Sambari’s claim, ascribing authorship to RS b. Hananya, arguing that provenance to the contrary is unreliable and supposed stylistic and linguistic inconsistencies also prove otherwise. [Shraga Abramson](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/abramson-shraga) (Sinai, vol. *C* pp. 22) agreed that the *mevo* commonly known as being from R. Shmuel HaNagid is only but a very abridged-translated version and “certainly improper to ascribe [such a work] to any important rabbi” (“וזה ודאי אינו ראוי לייחס לשום חכם חשוב”), although he disagreed with Margaliot as being from R. Shmuel b. Hananya and dismissed Margaliot’s proofs as “*shikul ha’daat*” (“his own discretion”; i.e. short of critical evidence) leaving the question of authorship unsolved and apparently only considered that the original treatise was by R. Shmuel b. Hofni.